# Have to touch back button twice to go to previous activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am quite new to Android so please be patient.

When you start a new activity, by default, the Back button on the device should take you back to the previous activity.
 
In my case I have to press the back button twice before it goes back to the previous activity.

Please advise

Comment: Have you tried debugging the actions to see what happends when you press back the first time? Are you sure you're not just starting the same activity twice, and then first back press closes last instance, and second press closes first instance , giving the impression that you have to press back twice to go back to a different action?

Comment: If you havent override the onBackPressed(), it is a weird behavior.

Comment: Very weird, just tested on another device and it works fine! Just happens on Samsung galaxy s2, the galaxy tab works correctly

Answer (score 3):

```
private int count = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    count++;
    if (count == 2) {
        //Do your stuff here
        count = 0;
    }    
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, counter should be reseted when taping screen/menu button/etc. In this case taping second time after a few minutes will still `do your stuff`.

Comment: @hsz I agree with you. I just give him the manner of doing it. But yes, its better to reset the variable when the user press the screen and the other buttons. But only him knows what he wants to really do (maybe he wants to have this during the entire life cycle of the activity)

Comment: Hi Shivan Dragon, thanks for the quick response. Dont think I explained correct, as is I have to click the back button twice before it goes back, I need the default behavior, click once to go back not twice.

Comment: Another case about reseting is to save last back press time (`long backPressTime`). If it is not grater than allowed delay, we `do your stuff`. Otherwise we just reset it to `0`.

Comment: In the log I get "no keyboard for id 0" on the first touch, and second touch "using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin"